# Trying to troubleshoot/understand mysqltuner JSON error message

Tags: json, mysqltuner

As per name I am just an old git who is attempting to teach himself so apologies if this is the wrong place/query for here.

Anyway I have run mysqltuner and am working through the recommendations - some are easier and more obvious, some I've managed to solve with a little research but this one stumps me.

Can someone point me in the right direction for some literature/solution.

Thanks in advance

```
failed to execute: SELECT CONCAT(QUOTE(user), '@', QUOTE(host)) FROM mysql.global_priv WHERE
    user != ''
    AND JSON_CONTAINS(Priv, '"mysql_native_password"', '$.plugin') AND JSON_CONTAINS(Priv, '""', '$.authentication_string')
    AND NOT JSON_CONTAINS(Priv, 'true', '$.account_locked')
[!!] FAIL Execute SQL / return code: 256
```

No idea where to start as google doesn't return anything specific

Comment: One possible reason for this error is that the `mysql.global_priv` table does not exist in the current MySQL server or the user running the query does not have sufficient privileges to access the table. Try `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'global_priv';`

Comment: global_priv - MySQL knows nothing about such table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?q=global_priv Maybe you use mysqltuner  for MariaDB? https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqlglobal_priv-table/

Comment: @oldgit71 MariaDB 10.3.10 does NOT have table named  mysql.global_priv  in this version.

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.global_priv;   We may be able to spot something with the query.

Comment: @oldgit71      Have you resolved your difficulties?

Comment: Hi, no I have not resolved it - purely because it has taken a major back seat to some medical news.....when/if I get round to this I'll take the advise/actions advised. Cheers